# Set floated div's text to float and wrap properly without hardcoding div width?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tTNNm/

How do you get the `div.text` to be floated next to the image div without hard-coding the width of `div.text` in the CSS?

A div is supposed to be the full width of whatever it's content is and then the height is supposed to be determined by how much of the content needs to wrap to the next line due to width constraints of it's parent element. So in my fiddle, how come the `div.text` takes on the full 300px width and force itself to the next line instead of fitting in next to the image's div with a calculated width of 200px?

Reference:

```
<div class="test">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.cadcourse.com/winston/Images/SoccerBall.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
    </div>
    <div class='text'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>​

div.test {
    width: 300px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
}

div.test div {
    float: left;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

​

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because both divs are inheritting the `float: left;`. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
div.test div.text {
    float: none;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Ah, very weird that I had to specify `div.test div.text` and not just `div.text`.  Thanks

Comment: @Jakobud you can probably just do div.text. CSS just inherits things unless explicitly declared.  For example: div.test div { ... } will apply that rule to any div within the div with the class of test.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense now. In the end, all I really needed to do was float the image div and leave the text div alone.

Answer (score 0):

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/tTNNm/12/) will make it so the text does not wrap around the image, but simply "resizes" the div to fit accordingly (assuming a 100px wide image).

### HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.cadcourse.com/winston/Images/SoccerBall.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
    </div>
    <div class='text'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.test {
    width: 300px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
}

div.test div.image {
    float: left;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
div.test div.text {
    outline: 1px solid orange;
    padding-left:110px;
}
```